# What exactly is non-interactive program?

Tags: wget

`man` page for `wget` says

```
NAME
   Wget - The non-interactive network downloader.

DESCRIPTION
   Wget is non-interactive, meaning that it can work in the background,
   while the user is not logged on.  This allows you to start a retrieval
   and disconnect from the system, letting Wget finish the work.  By
   contrast, most of the Web browsers require constant user's presence,
   which can be a great hindrance when transferring a lot of data.
```

`wget` is an example of non-interactive program I know. Now my question is,

- How can `wget` be used without user logged on?
- How does non-interactive programs work?

Comment: [What do we call Interactive in computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_computing).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you actually want to do. As is, the question seems somewhat vague.

Comment: Also, I think that if you **read** the information in the *description* section, your question will be already answered.

Comment: I have to agree Lucio.  The answer is in the question under the wget description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can wget be used without user logged on?

By including the wget command in a daemon/service or a program where you as a user do no initiate the download.

> How does non-interactive programs work?

When you create a deamon and have this daemon active it can continue to probe a server and ask for a download. If the servers is dead the non-interactive program will continue when the server is back up without any need for the user to act.

Updating Ubuntu, for instance, can be done without any action from a user and even without logging in.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way of running things while you are not logged in is by including a line in your crontab file:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/30 * * * * test -x /home/koju/bin/yourscript && /home/koju/bin/yourscript
```

The test is there to not to have `cron` complain via email when yourscript cannot be found.
For the format of the first fields look at `man 5 crontab`.

From `yourscript` you call wget, since it is **non-interactive** it will not prompt you to interact by asking for input. As long as the command line options of `wget` get you the information you need, the above set up will run for you every 30 minutes.

Of course you should test `yourscript` by starting it by hand, before committing it to run on a regular basis. You might find that wget is not powerful enough to do what you want, especially on web pages that require user-interaction above the basic login.